# /dev/fd/13:18: command not found: compdef

Tags: angular, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

Unable to type any commands in Mac terminal, and Visual Studio Code terminal.

Getting this error:

```
/dev/fd/13:18: command not found: compdef
```

[image: Issue in Mac Terminal and Visual Code terminal]

Comment: You did not say which shell you are running. If you are using zsh: You did not say how you executed `compinit`. Also it would help if you would post your `compdef` command.

Answer (score 1):

Open Mac terminal or Visual Studio Code terminal, and type:

open ~/.zshrc

after opening the `.zschrc` file. Now delete, or comment out, the following 2 lines as shown:

[image: solution]